# Property requires method to be defined in NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, core-data, protocols, categories, nsmanagedobject

I have some protocol like this:

```
@protocol UserProtocol <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *rating;

@end
```

Then I created some actual class that implements that:

```
@interface User : NSObject <UserProtocol>

@end
```

Now I need another implementation that uses `CoreData` so I created `CDUser` entity (`Xcode` also generates category for that):

```
// CDUser.h
@interface CDUser : NSManagedObject <UserProtocol>

@end

// CDUser+CoreDataProperties.h
@interface CDUser (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *rating;

@end

// CDUser+CoreDataProperties.m
@implementation CDUser (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic uid;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic rating;

@end
```

`CDUser` actually implements `UserProtocol` but I have warnings like so for all properties:

> Property 'uid' requires method 'uid' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

If I add `@dynamic uid;` again in `CDBook.m` then I get the following error:

> Property declared in category 'CoreDataProperties' cannot be implemented in class implementation

How can I solve these warnings in a proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause `CDUser` doesn't implement this protocol. Use protocol on category instead.

```
@interface CDUser : NSManagedObject

@end

// CDUser+CoreDataProperties.h
@interface CDUser (CoreDataProperties)  <UserProtocol>

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *uid;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *rating;

@end
```

Comment: This code is auto-generated by Xcode, so on next generation your protocols definitions will be removed.